# Python 3.5, if statement that calls an external command on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bash, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

I am writing a simple script to check sound output and then switch to another output (using os.system).

How do I check the sound output?
I want to use:

```
pacmd list cards | grep output\:
```

This is what is displayed:

```
        output:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 5460, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 360, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 360, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5200, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 5260, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 160, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:analog-stereo>
```

I want an if statement to check this bottom line "active profile:"
something like "if active profile == analog-stereo:"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) module to call external programs. It's up to you to do the chaining of calls, and parsing of output though.